# WP - How to change page title based on Page ID

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WP, I  want to add custom function to change the Page title of the page based on the Page ID or slug.?

I am trying to use this in functions.php

> global $wp_query;
>
> ```
>              if (is_page('1987')){
>               return $title;
>                   }
>
>               
>               $title = 'Sale';
>            
>               return $title;          }
> ```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30529/how-to-change-wordpress-post-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it with this.

```
function wpse309151_title_update( $title, $id = null ){
    
    
global $wp;
$current_slug = $wp->request;
   

    // See if this post is a direct child of Products
    if ($current_slug === 'page_slug_here') {
        // If it is, override the title
        $title = "SALE";
    }

    // Always return the title
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse309151_title_update', 10, 2 );


function wpse309151_remove_title_filter_nav_menu( $nav_menu, $args ) {
    // we are working with menu, so remove the title filter
    remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse309151_title_update', 10, 2 );
    return $nav_menu;
}
// this filter fires just before the nav menu item creation process
add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', 'wpse309151_remove_title_filter_nav_menu', 10, 2 );

function wpse309151_add_title_filter_non_menu( $items, $args ) {
    // we are done working with menu, so add the title filter back
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse309151_title_update', 10, 2 );
    return $items;
}
// this filter fires after nav menu item creation is done
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpse309151_add_title_filter_non_menu', 10, 2 );
```